# Find Next without leaving editor scope in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: aptana3

Exactly what sort of voodoo is required to Find some text in Aptana Studio, click in the PHP source editor window, make a change, and then Find Next without leaving the editor scope?

Obviously, Alt-N can be used to find next, but that changes the scope to the Find Dialog.

It appears that one should be able to bind a key, such as F3 and Ctrl G is by default, for Find Next, and set "When" option to one of the following: Aptana Editor, Editing Text, or PHP Source Editor; but doesn't work for me.

Does everyone just Ctrl-F to bring up the Find Bar, find find find, Esc, change something, Ctrl-F again (and hope you've not highlighted something because that replaces the text for which you were searching)?

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl+K for find next in the editor window. You can see a list of all the common commands with Ctrl + Shift + L.